# Transferred bitcoin to an address - they are gone - what can I find out?

Tags: wallet

I was transferring some bitcoin between online wallets to sell some.

I must have been distracted or something, I was transferring to a coinbase account. It has all been confirmed but the address it says it went to doesn't correspond to any coinbase addresses (not bitcoin, litecoin or ether).

I may have done something stupid here - but I'd like to find out what happened. I thought I might have entered an Ether address by accident - but as I say it doesn't correspond to my ether address listed on coinbase - + I read that the network would reject it anyway because it know's it's not a bitcoin address.

I have the to address - how can I research this further? I've found nothing on Google of help. thx.

The to address: 
1ACLteUzuXTYHV5v9nsoEk648hK8DShb4B

Comment: Go on blockchain.info

Comment: Yes I've seen that - but what does it tell me? If I can't get them back I'd at least like to know - say - which wrong crypto network I mistakenly tried to transfer the to (if that's possible) etc?

Comment: I've added the to address to the question

Comment: Well the money was received at that address, if you do not have the private keys for that address and Coinbase does not, there's no way of getting your money back. It is a valid BTC address and it received today 0.053BTC with 35 confirmations.

Comment: It can't be an ETH address, ETH and ETC starts with 0x . Maybe you sent to a Bitcoin Cash address? or to an old deposit BTC address. Have you checked [Tools->addresses](https://www.coinbase.com/addresses)?

Comment: the transfer was from blockchain

Comment: yeah im sure i copied and pasted that address from something that's mine - but its not showing up anywhere. So those confirmations mean its gone to a valid bitcoin address right?

Comment: it might be a bitcoin cash address - would that work?!

Comment: First thing will be to check if 1ACLteUzuXTYHV5v9nsoEk648hK8DShb4B is your BCH address in Coinbase. Remember to also check in [Tools->Addresses](https://www.coinbase.com/addresses)

Comment: YES its listed under my BCH addresses

Comment: If that is the case, then you have to ask Coinbase support nicely if they can recover those funds for you. There is a chance that you might need to sign the address you sent from to prove ownership of it.

Comment: awesome thanks - i guess the private keys are the same for both accounts - this gives me hope :D